# wcf сервер и soap запрос к нему

Tags: wcf, soap

Стоит задача обработки soap запроса. Однако почему то Soap запрос не выдержан по формату. а именно отсутствует SoapAction. 
Пример запроса с заголовками:

```
POST /gateway/service.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 830
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:8092
User-Agent: Fiddler

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://mis.er.atc.ru/ws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:SendRequest>
         <ws:MessageData>
            <ws:AppData>
               <ws:message>
                           fhgkjhgk
               </ws:message>
            </ws:AppData>
         </ws:MessageData>
      </ws:SendRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Проблема в том, что я создаю тока сервис принимающий этот запрос. То изменить запрос и добавить в него Action нет возможности. Подскажите есть ли при таком раскладе возможность принимать запрос и обрабатывать? Может как то возможно по умолчанию проставить action в конфиге сервиса?